# Variable as input Python returning false

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to follow these instructions:
[pythoninstructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkEmk.jpg)

Input

```py
menu = "salad,pasta,sandwich,pizza,drinks,dessert,chips,fries,soup,bread"
menuAsk = input("What are you looking for on the menu?: ").lower()
print(menuAsk)
print("menuAsk is found in menu = ",'menuAsk' in menu)
```

Output

```py
What are you looking for on the menu?: soup
soup
menuAsk is found in menu =  False
```

`soup` is in the menu, why is this returning `False`?

Comment: Before anyone can help you, please consult the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question accordingly. Especially for Python, the **indentation is essential**.

Comment: Its hard to understand what your question is, especially with the incorrect formatting, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: you are not checking the variable `menuAsk` but instead a string `"menuAsk"`, so it return `False`.

Comment: @costaparas https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28318581

Comment: I edited formatting and also added the instructions that I am trying to follow for more context.

Comment: You need to look up how to format a list of choices, or how to find a substring.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menu = "salad,pasta,sandwich,pizza,drinks,dessert,chips,fries,soup,bread" 
menuAsk = input("What are you looking for on the menu?: ").lower() 
print(menuAsk) 
print("menuAsk is found in menu = ",'menuAsk' in menu)
```

OK first, when posting a question, put four spaces before each code line and it gets formatted as code -- and you get better answers.

In line 4, your print statement has a first part `"menuAsk is found in menu = "`, and a second part `'menuAsk in menu`. I'm presuming you want the output to read `soup is found in menu = True`, right?

So for the first part to print `soup is found in menu =`  you have to tell the print statement that you want to print the **value of the variable** `menuAsk`, not simply to print the **string** 'menuAsk'. You do that with a formatted string, easiest way is `print(f'{menuAsk} is found in menu = ')`.

For the second part to print `True`, you need to evaluate if the **value** of `menuAsk` is in the string `menu`. You tried to evaluate if the string 'menuAsk' was in the `menu` string, which is always False. You want `menuAsk in menu`, dropping the quotes that made menuAsk into a string.

Bringing it together, you can put the second part inside curly braces in your print statement to evaluate it. That way your print statement can be simplified and corrected to read

```
print(f'{menuAsk} is found in menu = {menuAsk in menu}')
```

If you're not familiar with this kind of formatted print, you could break this down differently and assign a variable with value True/False to the expression `menuAsk in menu` e.g. with a line such as

```
item_was_on_the_menu = menuAsk in menu
```

And you could then rewrite your print statement, without the curly braces, as:

```
print(menuAsk,'is found in menu =', item_was_on_the_menu)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not working with a list, but a string.

```py
menu = ['salad', 'pasta', 'soup', 'bread']
target = input("I'm looking for... ").lower()
print(f'Is {target} in {menu}? - {target in menu}')

# Output:
# > I'm looking for... soup
# > Is soup in ['salad', 'pasta', 'soup' , 'bread'] - True
```

Comment: Thank you - I posted the instructions that I'm trying to follow for more context.